# Compiled class is different with maven goal "compile" and auto generated in target folder

Tags: maven, maven-compiler-plugin

In Spring3+Maven+Tomcat6 Web Project..

I try to use same RequestMapping in REST api Controller.
Because.. I need to different war with different usage.

So, I generated same name Controller, but different package.
For example...
1. xxx.controller.agent.UserController
2. xxx.controller.console.UserController

And in pom.xml..
1. maven -> build(war:war) -> get console.war include  xxx.controller.agent.UserController
2. uncomment the commented lines in testExcludes and excludes
3. comment the uncommented lines in testExcludes and excludes
4. maven -> update project configuration
5. maven -> build (war:war) -> get agent war include xxx.controller.console.UserController

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <testExcludes>
            <exclude>com/test/store/controller/agent/*.java</exclude>
            <exclude>com/test/rbac/controller/agent/*.java</exclude>
            <!-- <exclude>com/test/store/controller/console/*.java</exclude>
            <exclude>com/test/rbac/controller/console/*.java</exclude> -->
        </testExcludes>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>com/test/store/controller/agent/*Controller.java</exclude>
            <exclude>com/test/rbac/controller/agent/*Controller.java</exclude>                      
            <!-- <exclude>com/test/store/controller/console/*Controller.java</exclude>
            <exclude>com/test/rbac/controller/console/*Controller.java</exclude> -->
        </excludes>
        <source>1.6</source>
        <target>1.6</target>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

But, I don't want to edit pom.xml for each war build.
I try to build each war files using maven profiles element.
So, I edited my pom.xml as shown below..

```
<properties>
<exclude.console.store>com/test/store/controller/agent/**</exclude.console.store>
<exclude.console.rbac>com/test/rbac/controller/agent/**</exclude.console.rbac>
<exclude.agent.store>com/test/store/controller/console/**</exclude.agent.store>
<exclude.agent.rbac>com/test/rbac/controller/console/**</exclude.agent.rbac>
</properties>
...
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>console</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.2</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <packagingExcludes>
                            WEB-INF/classes/${exclude.console.store},
                            WEB-INF/classes/${exclude.console.rbac}
                        </packagingExcludes>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <testExcludes>
                            <exclude>${exclude.console.store}</exclude>
                            <exclude>${exclude.console.rbac}</exclude>                      
                        </testExcludes>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>${exclude.console.store}</exclude>
                            <exclude>${exclude.console.rbac}</exclude>                      
                        </excludes>
                        <source>1.6</source>
                        <target>1.6</target>
                        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>    
    </profile>

    <profile>
        <id>agent</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.2</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <packagingExcludes>
                            WEB-INF/classes/${exclude.agent.store},
                            WEB-INF/classes/${exclude.agent.rbac},
                            WEB-INF/classes/spring/task.xml
                        </packagingExcludes>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <testExcludes>
                            <exclude>${exclude.agent.store}</exclude>
                            <exclude>${exclude.agent.rbac}</exclude>                        
                        </testExcludes>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>${exclude.agent.store}</exclude>
                            <exclude>${exclude.agent.rbac}</exclude>                        
                        </excludes>
                        <source>1.6</source>
                        <target>1.6</target>
                        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>    
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

And Maven build.. (goal="package" or "compile war:war", profile="console" or "agent" in each case)
Build was success..(no compile error) but war is abnormal.
I copied war file to tomcat webapp directory, and execute startup.bat file.
In console log.. so many errors occured.
Maybe I think maven compile has some problems..
I unpacked the war file each build method(use profile and old method).
But, count of class file was different...

Thanks for your help, it's greatly appreciated!